# Is the axiom of foundation/axiom of regularity relatively consistent with ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#Regularity_and_the_rest_of_ZF(C)_axioms) says that the axiom of regularity is relatively consistent with the rest of ZF. Is the same true if we adjoin choice, i.e. is ZFC + regularity relatively consistent with ZFC?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is.

First, one minor note on wording: regularity is one of the axioms of ZFC, so what you actually want to show is that ZFC is relatively consistent with ZFC - regularity.

The argument is the same as showing ZF is consistent with ZF - regularity, except we need one more step for AC. Take AC to be the statement that every set is well-orderable (regularity is irrelevant to the standard equivalence proofs of this with AC or Zorn). Working in ZFC we define the class of well-founded sets $\mathrm{WF} = \bigcup_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}} V_\alpha$ and need to show that $\varphi^{\mathrm{WF}}$ holds for every ZFC axiom.

So the extra step is to just show that $(\mathrm{AC})^{\mathrm{WF}}$ holds. Let $A\in \mathrm{WF}.$ Then (by AC) there is a well-ordering $R$ of $A$. Well-foundedness is preserved by all the usual set operations and also that a subset of a well-founded set is well-founded, so since $R\subseteq A\times A,$ $R\in \mathrm{WF}.$

So all that's left is an absoluteness argument that "$R$ is a well-ordering of $A$" holds in the sense of $\mathrm{WF}.$ But this is easy to see: it says "for every nonempty $B\subseteq A$ there is an $x\in B$ such for all $z\in B,$ $z\not R x$," so given that the latter part (which is clearly absolute for transitive models) holds for every $B$ the universe, it holds for all $B\in \mathrm{WF}.$

(And as an irrelevant bonus, the relativized and unrelativized statements are actually equivalent since $B\subseteq A$ implies $B\in \mathrm{WF}$.)